# How do I D.R.Y. this code without making EF angry?

Tags: entity-framework, dry

The following is a WCF service that uses an EF4 entity set (`_catalog`) and another WCF service (`CatalogFilesServiceClient`).

```
    private CatalogEntities _catalog = new CatalogEntities();

    public IEnumerable<CategoryDC> GetCategories()
    {
        var catalogFiles = CatalogFilesServiceClient.Create();
        var missingFiles = catalogFiles.GetCategoriesMissingFiles();
        catalogFiles.Close();

        var categoryIDs = missingFiles.Select(i => i.EntityID ?? 0).Distinct();

        return from category in _catalog.Categories
               orderby category.Order
               select new CategoryDC
               {
                   ID = category.ID,
                   Alpha = category.Alpha,
                   Name = category.Name,
                   IsActive = (category.Status == "active"),
                   Description = category.Description,
                   Order = category.Order,
                   IsMissingFiles = (categoryIDs.Contains(category.ID)),
               };
    }

    public CategoryDC GetCategory(int a_nCategoryID)
    {
        var catalogFiles = CatalogFilesServiceClient.Create();
        var missingFiles = catalogFiles.GetCategoriesMissingFiles();
        catalogFiles.Close();

        var categoryIDs = missingFiles.Select(i => i.EntityID ?? 0).Distinct();

        var category = _catalog.Categories.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == a_nCategoryID);

        return new CategoryDC
            {
                ID = category.ID,
                Alpha = category.Alpha,
                Name = category.Name,
                IsActive = (category.Status == "active"),
                Description = category.Description,
                Order = category.Order,
                IsMissingFiles = (categoryIDs.Contains(category.ID)),
            };
    }
```

How do I not repeat the creation of `CategoryDC` in a way that won't make EF angry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```
private CatalogEntities _catalog = new CatalogEntities();

public IEnumerable<CategoryDC> GetCategories()
{
    return GetCategoriesAsQueryable();
}

public CategoryDC GetCategory(int a_nCategoryID)
{
    return GetCategoriesAsQueryable()
        .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == a_nCategoryID);
}

private IQueryable<CategoryDC> GetCategoriesAsQueryable()
{
    var catalogFiles = CatalogFilesServiceClient.Create();
    var missingFiles = catalogFiles.GetCategoriesMissingFiles();
    catalogFiles.Close();

    var categoryIDs = missingFiles.Select(i => i.EntityID ?? 0).Distinct();

    return from category in _catalog.Categories
           orderby category.Order
           select new CategoryDC
           {
               ID = category.ID,
               Alpha = category.Alpha,
               Name = category.Name,
               IsActive = (category.Status == "active"),
               Description = category.Description,
               Order = category.Order,
               IsMissingFiles = (categoryIDs.Contains(category.ID)),
           };
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that call `new CategoryDC` count-of-categories times?

Comment: @Jordan: The first method, yes (when the returned `IEnumerable` is enumerated somewhere (deferred execution)). It does the same like the first method in your question. The second method above, no, because of `SingleOrDefault` which is performed in the database.

Comment: I've known about deferred execution, but I didn't see it in this case. That's really cool. Thanks. :)

Comment: What if I have to do something to each category in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Jordan: I don't understand what you mean. Maybe ask a new question.